# Не работает переход между активити с помощью BottomNavigation

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-navigation-view

Класс в котором находится код для BottomNavigation

```
kotlin
abstract class BaseActivity:AppCompatActivity(){
    private val Tag = "BaseActivity"

    fun setupBottomNavigation(){
        BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            val next =
                when(it.itemId) {
                    R.id.menuIcon1 -> MainActivity::class.java
                    R.id.menuIcon2 -> FavouriteActivity::class.java
                    R.id.menuIcon3 -> AcountActivity::class.java
                    R.id.menuIcon4 -> AucCoinActivity::class.java
                    R.id.menuIcon5 -> BasketActivity::class.java
                    else -> {
                        Log.e(Tag, "unknown")
                        null
                    }
                }
            if (next != null) {
                val intent = Intent(this, next)
                startActivity(intent)
                true
            }else{
                false
            }
        }
    }
~
```

Класс наследуемый от BaseActivity

```
    class AcountActivity : BaseActivity() {
    private val Tag = "AcountActivity"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.account_layout)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        setupBottomNavigation()
    }
```

id иконок

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/menuIcon1"
            android:icon="@drawable/main"
            android:title="@string/main1" />
<menu/>
```

Comment: что значит не работает?

Comment: Переход не осуществляется путём нажатия на кнопку. И я ввиду большой неопытности даже не догадываюсь почему :(

Comment: а в логах что пишет?

Comment: V/AudioManager: playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=124KB, data=103KB
zygote64: After code cache collection, code=124KB, data=103KB
zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB

Comment: вы же видите, что этот кусочек логов совсем никак не относится к вашей проблеме

Comment: Это то что выводится в логах при нажатии, что должно относится я не знаю, если есть какие-то наводки чтобы я мог скинуть то что относится, подскажите брату меньшему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас как-то все сложно и запутанно сделано. Во-первых у вас только одна иконка почему-то в менюшке внизу, а активностей 5 нужно добавить наверное. Во-вторых так никто не работает с bottomNavigationView. Я имею в виду что никто активности не использует для этих целей, все можно сделать при помощи фрагментов которые намного легче активности и созданы как-раз для таких вот задач. Вот приблизительная реализация того что вы хотите сделать:

1. Делаем менюшку в ресурсах:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item
       android:id="@+id/navigation_shop"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_store_white_24dp"
       android:title="@string/title_shop" />

   <item
       android:id="@+id/navigation_gifts"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_card_giftcard_white_24dp"
       android:title="@string/title_gifts" />

   <item
       android:id="@+id/navigation_cart"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_white_24dp"
       android:title="@string/title_cart" />

   <item
       android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_white_24dp"
       android:title="@string/title_profile" />
   ```
2. Создаем разметку для одной активности которая будет родительской для всех фрагментов с контентом:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:id="@+id/container"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context="info.androidhive.bottomnavigation.MainActivity">

       <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/frame_container"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

       <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
           android:id="@+id/navigation"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="bottom"
           android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
           app:itemBackground="@color/bgBottomNavigation"
           android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
           app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
           app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
           app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
   ```
3. Вот код активности:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private ActionBar toolbar;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       toolbar = getSupportActionBar();

       BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
       navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

       toolbar.setTitle("Shop");
   }

   private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
           = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

       @Override
       public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
           Fragment fragment;
           switch (item.getItemId()) {
               case R.id.navigation_shop:
                   toolbar.setTitle("Shop");
                   return true;
               case R.id.navigation_gifts:
                   toolbar.setTitle("My Gifts");
                   return true;
               case R.id.navigation_cart:
                   toolbar.setTitle("Cart");
                   return true;
               case R.id.navigation_profile:
                   toolbar.setTitle("Profile");
                   return true;
           }
           return false;
       }
   };
   ```

   }
4. Делаем замещение фрагментов:

   ```
       private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
           = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

       @Override
       public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
           Fragment fragment;
           switch (item.getItemId()) {
               case R.id.navigation_shop:
                   toolbar.setTitle("Shop");
                   fragment = new StoreFragment();
                   loadFragment(fragment);
                   return true;
               case R.id.navigation_gifts:
                   toolbar.setTitle("My Gifts");
                   fragment = new GiftsFragment();
                   loadFragment(fragment);
                   return true;
               case R.id.navigation_cart:
                   toolbar.setTitle("Cart");
                   fragment = new CartFragment();
                   loadFragment(fragment);
                   return true;
               case R.id.navigation_profile:
                   toolbar.setTitle("Profile");
                   fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                   loadFragment(fragment);
                   return true;
           }

           return false;
       }
   };

   private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
       // load fragment
       FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
       transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
       transaction.addToBackStack(null);
       transaction.commit();
   }
   ```

и все)) Фрагмент такой-же как и активность и разобраться будет несложно как он работает. Не используйте активность для таких целей. Вот [статья](https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0) и вот [туториал_1](https://habr.com/ru/post/441618/) + [туториал_2](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-code-a-bottom-navigation-bar-for-an-android-app--cms-30305) + [туториал_3](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-navigation/) по интересующей вас тематике.

Comment: Благодарю, изучу, отвечу, разве что с ходу могу ответить на счёт 1ого, я просто вставил один, ибо не видел смысла добавлять еще, кода меньше читать :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый, не отвечайте фразами "Спасибо" и т.п.